# Python Type Dispatching with variables, is it possible?

Tags: python, types

I am developing a script that parses through a large number of IDs and want to build an abstraction that can hold all of these IDs. I also want this object to be able to be easily modified to add new IDs.

This is what I have so far:

```
class action: # abstraction for all IDs in an action
def __init__(self, dID=".", cID='.', dTp='.', dVs='.', mcID='.', aID='.', lID='.', pID='.', uID='.', uSe='.', udTp='.', componentID='.', eCx='.', eUr='.', eTp='.', rUrl='.', sec='.', oID='.', oVa='.', oCu='.', sID='.', saID='.', socNetworkUserID='.'):
    self._dID = dID
    self._cID = cID
    self._dTp = dTp
    self._dVs = dVs
    self._mcID = mcID
    self._aID = aID
    self._lID = lID
    self._pID = pID
    self._uID = uID #Display and Insights
    self._uSe = uSe
    self._udTp = udTp
    self._componentID = componentID
    self._eCx = eCx #Display and Insights
    self._eUr = eUr
    self._eTp = eTp #Display and Insights
    self._rUrl = rUrl
    self._sec = sec
    self._oID = oID #Display and Insights
    self._oVa = oVa
    self._oCu = oCu
    self._sID  = sID
    self._saID = saID
    self._socNetworkUserID = socNetworkUserID
    self._empty_params = []

def insert_id_val(self, name, value): #Utility method
    return

def insert_id_val_display(self, name, value):
    item_map = {"dID" : _dID, "cID" : _cID, "dTp" : _dTp, "dVs" : _dVs, 
                "mcID" : _mcID, "aID" : _aID, "lID" : _lID, "pID" : _pID,
                "uID" : _uID, "uSe" : _uSe, "udTp" : _udTp, "componentID" : _componentID,
                "eCx" : _eCx,"eUr" : _eUr, "eTp" : _eTp, "rUrl" : _rUrl,
                "sec" : _sec, "oID" : _oID, "oVa" : _oVa, "oCu" : _oCu,
                "socNetworkUserID" : _socNetworkUserID, "_" : _empty_params}
    self.item_map[name] = value

def insert_id_val_insights(self, name, value):
    item_map = {"eTp" : self._eTp, "eCx" : self._eCx, "uID" : self._uID, "oID" : self._oID,
                "sID" : self._sID, "saID" : self._saID}
    item_map[name] = value
```

I tried two ways of doing type dispatching with two different ways, in the two different insert functions, but they both error. I have seen examples where people do things like [Type-Dispatching Example](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/MultipleDispatching.html)
but they don't show how to use type dispatching with setting, only getting.

My implementation gives:

```
global name '_dID' is not defined at line 193 of program.py
```

How does one use type dispatching with setting variables? Is it even possible? If not, how else can I quickly make an abstraction like the one above without having to type a bunch of if statements?

EDIT: To add, I cannot instantiate the object with all of the IDs as their values are not known at instantiation.

Comment: Have you considered  having your class inherit from the `dict` class?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more? @MichaelPetch

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure what you're asking here, or what exactly you mean by type dispatching. If you're asking about how to dynamically set attributes in a class, you can easily do that with `**kwargs`:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

and now you can instantiate it with `action(dID='foo', oID='bar')` and refer internally to `self.dID` and `self.oID`.

Comment: Well I guess it would be Dynamic Dispatch but with attributes instead of functions. Also, (shoulda stated in question, will update) each ID is added into the object one by one, and not know during instantation, so I don't think the above would work very well..?

Comment: Well, remember Python is not Java. You can set any attribute onto an object at any time, so you can always do `my_action_instance.myID = 'my_value'`.

Comment: True, but that would require if statements for every ID, no? I'm trying to avoid having redundant and lengthy if statements in the code. The thing with setting the ID values is that if statements are still needed, since python won't know which ID attribute to set, right? I'm guessing that there is no avoiding it then?